# Khet opening set-ups

Tags: openings, khet

What are the different merits of the [Khet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khet_%28game%29) opening set-ups - Classic, Imhotep & Dynasty?

Answer (score 4):

While I wouldn't call myself an expert, I have played a lot, and here are some of my thoughts on the matter.

Classic is the most simple of the three, and does not lend itself to defence, both players are rather open. For this reason, classic games tend to be short when the players know what they are doing.

Dynasty is my personal favorite. The defences of this setup are very tight. Players normally will have to attack from both the front and side. This results in long games, while players march up the side and get into position.

Lastly, Imhotep! Imhotep opens a lot of options; the defences are good, but not too tight, and many types of pieces are scattered across the board. The end game is often a dance of hiding the opening in your defences long enough to close in on the enemy.

I developed a fourth one a while back, mainly for use with the beam splitter, but still good without it, if I can find it somewhere around here, I will post it if you like.

So there you go, there you have it.

Comment: Hello Timothy.  Welcome to the site and thanks for jumping in with such a long-unanswered question; this one's been bugging me for over a year.

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad to share the little knowledge I have.